# CakePHP 3 - How to pass object data in email template

Tags: email, cakephp

How to pass object data in email template?
Object data:

```
    object(App\Model\Entity\NewsletterTemplate) {

        'id' => (int) 1,
        'title' => 'Newsletter 1',
        'publish' => '21.04.2016',
        'box_title1' => 'Aenean id erat ut leo semper viverra',
        'box_text1' => 'Integer eu orci viverra',
...
    }
```

E-mail function:

```
private function _send_mail($data,$user,$sender)
{
 $email = new Email('default');
 $email->template('newsletter_template','newsletter_body')
 ->emailFormat('html')
 ->subject('Newsletter')
 ->to($user)
 ->from([$sender => 'Some Name'])
 ->viewVars($data)
 ->send();
}
```

I tried this but it does not work (E-mail template newsletter_template.ctp):

```
...
                        <td class="mcnTextContent mcnTextContentLeft" style="padding-top:0; padding-left:18px; padding-bottom:9px; padding-right:18px;" valign="top">                       
                            <?php echo $title; ?>, <?php echo $publish; ?>
...
                        </td>
```

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description! Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead. Show the data that you are working with, the context, your debugging attempts, and possible errors. Often the problem solves itself when collecting these information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails) reports

you can set email view variables in this way:

```
$email->viewVars([
    'title' => $title,
    'publish' => $publish
]);
```

of course you can pass the whole entity too using this method